# "Жить -- родине служить". Где здесь подлежащее?

Tags: грамматика

Где подлежащее и где сказуемое в предложении ***"Жить -- родине служить"***? Мне этот вопрос задала иностранная студентка, и я растерялся (я не филолог).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Подлежащее – "Жить", сказуемое – "родине служить".

Та же структура в предложении "Понять – значит простить".

Аналог в английском:

“To live is the rarest thing in the world. Most people exist, that is all.”

― Oscar Wilde

Comment: а что является сказуемым в предложении "Понять – значит простить"? в отличие от первого здесь есть явное сказуемое "значит", или сказуемым является вся связка "значит простить"?

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка, Сказуемое тут - "значит простить", где "значит" - это связка (копула): http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?id=58_220&layout=item Тире тут, кстати, не очень уместно, так как ничего не опущено. Просто скопировал откуда-то.

Comment: если исходить из содержания п. 3 в статье на Грамота.ру, тире здесь употреблено правильно

Comment: Действительно п. 3 рекомендует ставить тире. My bad.

Answer (score 2):

The subject is *жить*, and there is no verb in this sentence.

The word *значит* is an assumed but not explicitly expressed verb here.

Please note that the Russian linguistic term *сказуемое* is usually conveyed in English as "predicate", however it's more strict than the English term. It only applies to the grammatical role in a sentence, not the semantic one.

Let me quote an article from the Linguistic Encyclopaedic Dictionary:

> В языкознании для некоторых языков (в западноевропейских терминологических систе­мах) термин «предикат» был использован при обозначении состава предложения, соответ­ству­ю­ще­го сообщаемому, а также «ядерного» компонента этого состава (англ. *predicate*, франц. *prédicat*, исп. *predicado*, итал. *predicato*). Для других языков (например, славянских) этот термин был заменен калькой «сказуемое», что позволило избежать термино­ло­ги­че­ско­го смешения логических и грамматических категорий, но не исключён из лингвистического обихода. С термином «сказуемое» ассоциируется прежде всего формаль­ный аспект этого члена предложения, с термином «предикат» — его содержательный аспект.

In your sentence, *родине служить* is a predicate but not a (grammatical) verb.

Comment: Да, я понимаю насчет "значит" -- я-то русский :) Просто я не филолог и плохо знаю формальную грамматику, теряюсь в не совсем тривиальных ситуациях. Спасибо!

Comment: "there is no verb in this sentence" -- Really? I see two.

Comment: @SergeySlepov: what you are seeing is morphological verbs (*глаголы*), not grammatical verbs (*сказумые*), which I believe is what the OP was asking about. There is no grammatical verb in this sentence, although there is a predicate.

Comment: Сказуемое = predicate.

Comment: @SergeySlepov: not quite! see my update